# Comment rend-on en français cet emprunt que l'anglais fait au français du mot « métier » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, comparaison-de-langues

Dans une [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/225049) sur la langue *anglaise*, on explore indirectement l’emprunt du mot « *métier* » au français. L'emploi en anglais remonte à [1792](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=metier), mais l'utilisation qu'on en fait semble différente à certains égards ([*NED*](https://archive.org/stream/oed6barch#page/396/mode/1up), extraits) :

> A trade or profession: in Eng. use chiefly [*transf.*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transferred_sense), a person's
>   'line', that in which one is specially skilled.
>
> 1792 CHARLOTTE SMITH *Desmond* I xiii 253 *They wanted, indeed, to make
>   me a monk; but I had a mortal aversion to that métier*. 1842
>   BARHAM[...] *Heretic-burning - in fact, 'tis his métier*.
>
> [ NED(OED1) ]

N'y a-t-il pas là un apport à l'évaluation, celui de la personnalité, du caractère, au-delà de l'expérience ou de la formation ? Dans une des [réponses](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/225164) on présente une référence à l'effet que *métier* et je cite "*implies a calling or pursuit for which one believes oneself to be especially fitted {acting was my one and only métier}*." et l'auteur abonde dans ce sens-là plus loin dans sa réponse.

---

En *français*, le [métier](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9tier) c'est issu du [*ministère*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/gaffiot/ministerium) avec une influence possible du [*mystère*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/gaffiot/mysterium). C'est donc à l'origine associé au service religieux, puis à une fonction, aux lettrés etc. Par la suite, entre le 15ième et le 16ième, apparaissent les sens d'*artisan* et d'*ouvrier*, très usuels. Dans le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, M. Rey nous enseigne que tous les sens latins sont encore disponibles pour ce mot. Sauf qu'en regardant au *TLFi* ou au *Littré*, on peine à y croire. Au sens 5 et 6, le  [*Littré*](http://www.littre.org/definition/m%C3%A9tier) semble même aller dans le sens contraire(mes italiques):

> *5* Habileté d'exécution, *mais rien de plus*, en parlant de la peinture,
>   de la sculpture ; le talent acquis de vaincre facilement la matière.
>   Avoir du métier.
>
> *6* Par extension, profession *quelconque*. Le métier des armes.
>
> [...]
>
> *Homme du métier*, homme qui se connaît à une chose ; *être du métier*, se
>   connaître à une chose.
>
> [ *Dictionnaire Littré* ]

Ce qui ressemble le plus au *métier* anglais c'est peut-être cette idée du rôle :

> *Il faut que je me mette à mon métier de père de famille, que je marie
>   mon Hortense et que j'enterre le libertin* (Balzac, Cous. Bette, 1846,
>   p. 73).
>
> [ *TLFi* ]

C'est presque le métier qui « *interpelle* ». Mais ce n'est pas du même registre qu'en anglais, où c'est même plus soutenu et intime à la fois que la *profession*. En français on voit « sot métier », « métier de rêve », « à chacun son métier », « le plus vieux métier du monde » et bien d'autres, mais on n'a pas, je crois, ce métier qui « fit »... à quelqu'un... de manière « ontologique ».

---

Peut-on employer le métier en français dans le sens abordé dans la première partie ? Autrement comment rend-on cet emprunt que l'anglais fait au français du mot *métier* ? Comment cela s'applique-t-il aux *deux exemples* de 1792 et de 1842 présentés plus haut ?

Comment: Sans connaître le sens anglais de _métier_, le contexte religieux du premier exemple me fait penser à _vocation_.

Comment: @mouviciel Oui, moi aussi. Mais pas pour le deuxième exemple. Une réponse pourrait tenter de rendre les deux exemples purement en fonction du contexte...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(SEE **ADDITION** BELOW MY ORIGINAL ANSWER)

It seems that the transferred sense of "métier" in English has first been "loosened" (as is apparently usually the case) in the sense of "expanded" to include the notion "in which one is specially skilled," (which notion is, in my opinion, missing in all the original French meanings), and then curiously "(re)-tightened" to mean that, and only (or primarily) that newly expanded sense.

Therefore, based primarily on your analysis of the word's meanings, I'd say that "métier" in French does not fully (or at least not automatically) capture the notion of "specially skilled" (although "rôle," as you state, comes close, as does, in my opinion, "Homme du métier, homme qui se connaît à une chose ; être du métier, se connaître à une chose.")

To find an option in French that kind of captures this "specially skilled" notion, I started with the rather curious use of "line" in the cited NED extract and arrived at **"un/mon/son rayon"**, which according to my Le Robert-Micro can mean: 3/III/2. "Domaine particulier. 'Je regrette, ce n'est pas **mon rayon**, ce n'est pas de ma compétence...'"

To make a connection from "rayon"/"line" back to the two cited English uses, I suppose that one could simply use "line" or "line of work," but they wouldn't necessarily capture the "specially skilled" notion, so maybe "line of expertise" would work, although that might be going a bit beyond the notion of "specially skilled." ("line of expertise" makes me think of "*field* of expertise" or even just "*field*" to replace "métier" **in English**, but I'm not sure how to connect "field" to "rayon" to get it back to "métier" in French)

**ADDITION:**

Upon further reflection, I think it’s worth noting that both of the examples you give of the use of “métier” in English involve religious vocations/functions.  Furthermore, as you and the cited ELU answer both note, the usage of “métier” in English dates from 1792, from which one could deduce that Charlotte Smith was the first to so use it.  Being the first and therefore defining user of it, perhaps an examination of the possible reasons behind her decision to use it as she did, in a “religious vocation/function” context, might shed some light on both the English and French issues.

Normally I would first think of using [“calling”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_calling) when discussing religious vocations and functions in English and I think that it’s possible that the two authors, especially Smith, being the word’s first borrower, were simply looking for a suitable word to replace “calling” in their respective religious (borderline sacrilegious?) contexts.

For whatever reason, instead of coming right out and using the English “calling,” with its “heavenly” connotations, along side of the arguably incongruous notion of “mortal aversion to,” in the 1792 example and along side of the arguably overly enthusiastic description of “heretic-burning” in the 1842 example, the authors turned instead to the French “métier,” thinking, based perhaps on their awareness of the word’s “service religieux”/ («le service divin (spirituel, liturgique, pastoral)» origins, that “métier” adequately captured the religious vocation/function (l'appel à [or de] Dieu) sense of “calling” that they were after, no more no less.

In my mind, it's arguable that the use of “métier” in purely religious contexts to capture the full “religious vocation/function” sense of “a calling for which one is especially fitted” technically doesn’t require expansion of its meaning in French; it simply requires knowledge of and reversion to the word’s original “service religieux” meaning, with the “special fitness” being implied.  Implied, because who, at least at the time of the word’s origins (881?), would have dared to question one’s fitness when “the call” came from the Big Guy/Gal Him/Herself?

Expansion upon the French meaning, however, is required when “métier” is used in English outside of purely religious contexts, and it’s possible that this expansion to include the notion of “[non-devine/quasi-devine] callings/vocations/functions for which one is especially fitted” could be best captured in French by words that have both purely “ecclésiastique” meanings as well as non-(or at most quasi-) “ecclésiastique” meanings.

With this in mind, I now propose two new candidates as possible answers to your question.

The first new candidate that would seem to contain the above dualism is [“état,” (4-Profession, condition)](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9tat) which my “Le Robert & Collins” French/English Dictionary (1999) lists as the second of two translations of “calling” (after vocation), and which under meaning [II:- B.- 2. here at cnrtl.fr](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9tat) has both purely religious and non-religious senses:

> II.− Situation d'une personne du point de vue de l'ordre social.
>
> B.-[Sur le plan soc.]
>
> 2 . P. méton. Profession, travail, tâche. Apprendre, avoir, embrasser, prendre un état; faire son état; horloger de son état :
>
> 21. L'état de charpentier m'a toujours plu. « L'état de charpentier! s'écria mon oncle avec une sorte d'explosion de joie, tu n'es vraiment
>     pas dégoûté. Je ne t'en aurais jamais indiqué un autre. Le
>     charpentier, mon enfant, c'est dans ses chantiers que notre divin
>     Maître a daigné choisir son père adoptif... » Nodier, Fée
>     Miettes,1831, p. 72.
>
> ♦ État ecclésiastique, militaire. Parmi les
> métaphysiciens françois qui ont professé la doctrine de Locke, il faut
> compter au premier rang Condillac, que son état de prêtre obligeoit à
> des ménagements envers la religion, et Bonnet, qui, naturellement
> religieux, vivoit à Genève dans un pays où les lumières et la piété
> sont inséparables (Staël, Allemagne,t. 4, 1810, p. 56).Il [l'oncle
> Edme] exaltait l'état militaire, l'honneur des officiers, la vertu des
> Jacobins et distribuait des pièces d'argent à ses jeunes auditeurs
> s'ils promettaient de combattre, plus tard, pour le roi de Rome (Adam,
> Enf. Aust.,1902, p. 191).

I ran across my second new candidate, [“sacerdoce” (4-(Figuré) Vocation)](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sacerdoce),  in the “etymology/history” section near the bottom of the cnrtl.fr site you provided for “métier.” “Sacerdoce” was totally new to me, which explains why I needed to look it up and in the process discovered that it has the "requisite" dual, religious & non/quasi-religious, meanings.
[For “sacerdoce,”](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sacerdoce) cnrtl.fr gives the following, quasi-religious meaning in which the word “vocation” is given as a synonym (which gets me back to my old “Le Robert & Collins” French/English Dictionary and its first entry for “calling”):

> − P. anal. Fonction qui revêt un caractère quasi-religieux par la
> vertu et le dévouement qu'elle exige. Synon. vocation. Sacerdoce
> politique; sacerdoce de la magistrature, du professorat; s'acquitter
> d'une tâche comme d'un sacerdoce. Ces guides du Sahara sont des
> personnages respectés (...) ils exercent une sorte de sacerdoce
> (Sainte-Beuve,Nouv. lundis, t. 9, 1864, p. 119).Mon respect s'accrut
> pour ce saint homme dont le dévouement ne trouvait pas de récompense:
> je fus préparé de bonne heure à traiter le professorat comme un
> sacerdoce et la littérature comme une passion (Sartre,Mots, 1964, p.
> 33).
>
> − P. métaph. Je crois que mes vieux frères [les républicains]
> doivent frapper de grands coups, et que vous [les saint-simoniens],
> revêtus d'un sacerdoce d'innocence et de paix, vous ne pouvez tremper
> dans le sang des combats vos robes lévitiques (Sand,Corresp., t. 1,
> 1836, p. 342).

To the extent that even the non-religious/quasi-religious sense of “sacerdoce,” all by itself, might seem too strong to identify and capture the missing French meaning of “métier” that you seek, perhaps you could still look to the above entry from cnrtl.fr and, although not single words, use one of the following curious phrases contained therein:  “comme [d']un sacerdoce” or “une sorte de sacerdoce.”

Using my two new candidates in your examples would give the following (although, as I tried to explain above, I think the original “service religieux” French meaning of “métier” for contexts involving "religious vocations/functions," such as these, doesn't necessary need to be expanded):

> **with "état":**
>
> 1792 CHARLOTTE SMITH Desmond I xiii 253 They wanted, indeed, to make
> me a monk; but I had a mortal aversion to 'that métier/calling' (=
> 'cet état').
>
> 1842 BARHAM[...] Heretic-burning - in fact, 'tis 'his métier/calling'
> (= 'son état').
>
> **with "sacerdoce":**
>
> 1792 CHARLOTTE SMITH Desmond I xiii 253 They wanted, indeed, to make
> me a monk; but I had a mortal aversion to 'that métier/calling' (=
> 'cet (le) sacerdoce').
>
> 1842 BARHAM[...] Heretic-burning - in fact, 'tis 'his métier/calling'
> (= 'son sacerdoce').
>
> **and finally with “comme [d']un sacerdoce” or “une sorte de sacerdoce.”**
>
> 1792 CHARLOTTE SMITH Desmond I xiii 253 They wanted, indeed, to make
> me a monk; but I had a mortal aversion to 'that métier/calling' (=
> 'cette sorte de sacerdoce').
>
> (this one shows well, I think, that "métier" (in its original sense of
> "religious service") really doesn't need to be replaced/expanded upon
> in this context, at least not by the quasi/non-religious sense of
> sacerdoce, but then again its ambiguous use here could help the author
> to emphasize the disdain/sarcasm that her character exhibits towards
> monks (or at least towards being one) that the use of "mortal aversion
> to" clearly implies to me)
>
> 1842 BARHAM[...] Heretic-burning - in fact, 'tis 'his métier/calling'
> (= [c'est] 'comme son sacerdoce').

Comment: Thank you! Taking the position that they would have wanted to replace _calling_ in those religious contexts by using _métier_, you cast this more as a specific functional application. Like "religiously", something we expect from the behavior of someone who has the_calling_. "Shopping" for words that contain a religious meaning as well as a "spin" so to speak is very ingenious imho. _État_ often more with what would look like "Brûleur d'hérétiques de son état" imho lol but interesting. _Sacerdoce_ is more personal & also allows "l'essence de son" without qualifying the métier per se. Tiptop! Ty

Answer (score 2):

La citation de *Smith* en contexte dans [*Desmond*](https://archive.org/stream/desmondnovelintw01smit#page/152) :

> [...]for though I was bred a sailor, and loved fighting well enough, I
>   was refused even as *Ensigne de Vaisseau*, on board a King's ship,
>   because I was not a gentleman- My father, however, had a pretty little
>   estate, which he inherited from his great, great grandfather- But he
>   had an older son, and I was to scramble through the world as well as I
>   could- *They wanted, indeed, to make me a monk; but I had a mortal
>   aversion to that métier,* and thought it better to run the risk of
>   having my head taken off by a cannon ball than to shave it[...]

Une note de bas de page indique « trade - profession » pour *métier*. Un élément déterminant c'est peut-être que si l'emploi était soutenu pour ce mot uniquement, alors que le contexte l'est peu ou pas, on pourrait alors lui préférer **profession** ici selon moi. Autrement, on a mentionné la [**vocation**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vocation) en commentaire - *l'appel à Dieu* - qui se rattache bien avec le sujet des ordres religieux et ainsi aux sens plus anciens du métier. Par ailleurs, il s'agit aussi d'un récit d'aventure raconté assez familièrement à la première personne, et on pourrait peut-être utiliser ici quelque chose comme « mais ce n'était vraiment pas mon [*bail*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bail) » (ou peut-être [*rayon*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13071/3177)). Mais rien ne s'oppose directement à ce qu'on utilise *j'avais une aversion mortelle pour(ou horreur de) ce métier* ici, à mon avis.

---

La citation de *Barham* en contexte dans *The auto-da-fé: a legend of Spain* dans [*The Ingoldsby Legends*](http://www.exclassics.com/ingold/ingintro.htm):

> And then for a Cook
>  We
>   have not far to look--
>  Father Dominic's self, Sire, your own
>   Grand Inquisitor,
>  Luckily now at your Court is a visitor;
>  Of
>   his Rev'rence's functions there is not one weightier
>  Than
>   *Heretic-burning -- in fact, 'tis his métier.*

Comme en témoigne la phrase qui précède la citation, ça « rime », et c'est présenté comme la *fonction* la plus importante pour un politique religieux de l'époque. Alors justement, on pourrait utiliser la *fonction*, le *rôle/devoir* ou la **mission** ici. Le *lot*(ce qui échoit à qqn.) ou la *charge* (une responsabilité qui "pèse") s'arriment bien à l'idée de la lourdeur ou de l'importance, mais ils ont aussi cette connotation de "fardeau" qui pourrait s'opposer à la vision du narrateur(la gaieté dans l'exécution de la tâche à accomplir?! - sans savoir si c'est partagé par le révérend lui-même). Finalement, peut-être que « brûler les hérétiques » *c'est la définition/nature de son métier* - «  c'est ça *que* son métier/travail »; mais il me semble que c'est introduire là un constat sur la fonction que le texte n'autorise peut-être pas. La rime pose un défi supplémentaire... À mon avis, quoique possible, il manquerait à *métier* utilisé seul ici ce petit quelque chose qui évacuerait la connotation d'une tâche sans réelle importance, répétitive à laquelle on porte peu attention. L'enthousiasme semble plus grand!

---

L'emprunt peut avoir un sens différent du sens d'origine et je crois que c'est le cas ici - essentiellement plus soutenu et ancien. Un plus grand contexte est souvent plus utile que d'établir la différence exacte de sens entre les deux langues. On peut essayer de rendre directement par *métier* puisqu'il disposerait de tous les sens originaux. Mais dans le premier exemple, une question se pose à savoir si une nuance est perdue quand on rend directement par *métier*, alors que dans le deuxième, toute l'intensité ou l'importance requise n'est peut-être pas entièrement au rendez-vous. Il y a plusieurs « sens » à préserver et c'est matière à réflexion.

Comment: Je ne suis pas assez versé dans la compréhension de la poésie en langue anglaise, mais pour le deuxième exemple je pense à deux mots dont les connotations pourraient éventuellement donner des éclairages intéressants: **C'est sa croix**, ou plus ironique: **C'est sa passion**.